# Passing 2D Array As Formal Parameter, Getting Single String

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm passing a 2D array as an argument. Reviewing the array in main shows that I have 4 separate strings of words each being stored in words[1][], words[2][], etc. However, when I pass that array to the function I am using to append plural endings, I only seem to be able to access the first string in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define ROWS 50
#define COLS 50

void readFileFormat(char words[ROWS][COLS]);
void determinePlurals(char words[ROWS][COLS]);

int main()
{
    char words[ROWS][COLS];

    readFileFormat(words);
    determinePlurals(words);

    return 0;
}

void readFileFormat(char words[ROWS][COLS])
{
    int cols = 0;//consistent cols for 2d array

    FILE* nounFile;

    fopen_s(&nounFile, "plural.txt", "r");

    if (nounFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error reading file; try again.");
        return 1;
    }

    while (!feof(nounFile))
    {
        for (int rows = 0; rows < ROWS; ++rows)
        {
            fgets(&words[rows][cols], 50, nounFile);
            words[rows][strcspn(words[rows], "\n")] = 0;
        }
    }
    
    fclose(nounFile);
}

void determinePlurals(char words[ROWS][COLS])
{
    char* iesEnd = "ies";
    char* esEnd = "es";
    char* sEnd = "s";

    for (int rows = 0; rows < ROWS; ++rows)
    {
        if (strcmp(words[rows] + strlen(words[rows]) - 1, "y") == 0)
        {
            printf("%s: ", words);
            words[rows][strlen(words[rows]) - 1] = '\0';
            strncat(words[rows], iesEnd, 3);
            printf("%s\n", words);
            rows++;

        }
        else if (strcmp(words[rows] + strlen(words[rows]) - 2, "ch") == 0
            || strcmp(words[rows] + strlen(words[rows]) - 2, "ss") == 0
            || strcmp(words[rows] + strlen(words[rows]) - 2, "x") == 0
            || strcmp(words[rows] + strlen(words[rows]) - 2, "sh") == 0)
        {
            printf("%s: ", words);
            strncat(words[rows], esEnd, 2);
            printf("%s\n", words);
            rows++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s: ", words);
            strncat(words[rows], sEnd, 1);
            printf("%s\n", words);
            rows++;
        }
    }       
}
```

I've tried iterating through each row, but don't seem to have acccess to the rest of words[][]. I've struggled with multidimensional arrays so I'm looking for a bit of assistance.

Comment: Your compiler will be giving you many, many warnings about wrong types here. You need to fix those. Also, please include all your code. You did not show us readFileFormat().

Comment: I'm only getting a warning for using an int return on 'readFileFormat' or that I'm using strncat instead of strncat_s. Also, updated and added my 'readFileFormat' fuction.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/1216776

Comment: The many problems in this code demonstrate that you've first typed the program, and now hope to debug it (or have someone re-write it for you.) eg #1 "loading words" The program will keep calling `fgets()` until it has called the function 50 times. Fix that. eg #2, "row++"... The function increments the row counter in each 'case' and increments it again as the last term of the `for()` loop... Start over with a program that simply loads each line and displays it. Test and debug before adding more functionality like arrays and then checking/changing to make words plural.

Comment: You're right, I did dive in with limited to no design. Apologies as the goal was not to have someone do the work for me. Appreciate the feedback regardless.